# Is it possible to install Robot Framework without installing Python on Windows?

Tags: java, python, windows, jython, robotframework

I have Java 1.6. And I have installed Jython on Windows by following the steps below:

1. Download "jython-installer-2.7-b1.jar"
2. Open command prompt --> Go to the location/folder where jython-installer-2.7-b1.jar is kept
3. Execute the command java -jar jython-installer-2.7-b1.jar
4. Jython installation GUI is opened and follow the instruction to install jython
5. Set Path and JYTHON_HOME (In my case it was "C:\jython2.7b1\bin" and "C:\jython2.7b1" respectively)

Jython is installed successfully. Now I want to install Robot Framework. I tried to install Robot Framework using "robotframework-2.7.7.win32.exe" . At the 2nd step the following information message was displayed:
"No Python installation found in the registry"

So, I have understood Python is mandatory to install Robot Framework. But, I want to install Robot Framework without installing Python using Jython. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this framework before, but from what I understood from the documentation and based on my Java experience, I would recommend you to download the Standalone JAR Package (which, for the latest version is: robotframework-2.7.7.jar (at http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/downloads/detail?name=robotframework-2.7.7.jar&can=2&q= )

According to the Wiki and the download notes, this package is standalone and already contains Jython, so it doesn't require additional installations of anything besides Java.

You can confirm this at: http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/Installation#Stand-alone_JAR_package

Comment: This should be accepted answer. The Standalone JAR distribution of RF has Java as the only dependency and is available through Maven Central. CHECK_1: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/INSTALL.rst#standalone-jar-distribution CHECK_2:  http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3Arobotframework BUT the downside of it is that some third party libraries are not fully Jython compatible - I am not sure if it is still the case but in the past the popular Selenium2Library and Jython were not friends.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.7.7#using-windows-installer), the Windows installer needs Python to be installed. Perhaps you can uninstall it once Robot Framework in installed (not tested).

If you're ok with Jython 2.5, you should use the [standalone JAR distribution](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/downloads/list). If you really want Jython 2.7, then you may need to [install from source](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.7.7#installing-from-source), but it really doesn't look complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Can I write tests in Robot Framework with java?